# Vlc won't work with framelesswindow and transparent/translucent background in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, vlc, libvlc

i am making a window which plays video with vlc.
Here is my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore,QtGui
import vlc
class Player(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600,400)
        self.mainframe=QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainframe)
        self.mainframe.setStyleSheet("background:grey;border-radius:15px;")
        self.videoframe=QtWidgets.QFrame(self.mainframe)
        self.videoframe.setGeometry(10,10,580,380)
        self.videoframe.setStyleSheet("background:#333333")
        '''
        If i want to set transparent background and frameless window,video wont display only audio plays
        '''
        # self.setWindowFlags(
        #           QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint 
        #         | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint )
        # self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.instance=vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.player.set_hwnd(int(self.videoframe.winId()))
        media = self.instance.media_new('C:/Users/mishra/Downloads/Video/despacito.mp4')
        media.parse()
        self.player.set_media(media)
        self.player.play()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Player()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i can hear only audio playing but no video if i set

```
self.setWindowFlags(
             QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint 
            | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint )
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

It also throws a lot of errors but that error does not affect.The errors i got is

```
[00757578] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
[02620b80] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
[043ccc28] direct3d11 vout display error: Could not Create the D3D11 device. (hr=0x80004001)
[043ccc28] direct3d11 vout display error: Direct3D11 could not be opened
[043ccc28] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[025fc198] d3d11va generic error: D3D11CreateDevice failed. (hr=0x80004001)
[025fc198] d3d11va generic error: Failed to create device
[043ccc28] direct3d9 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[04384af8] direct3d11 vout display error: Could not Create the D3D11 device. (hr=0x80004001)
[04384af8] direct3d11 vout display error: Direct3D11 could not be opened
[04384af8] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[025fbe38] dxva2 generic error: FindVideoServiceConversion failed
[04384af8] direct3d9 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
[04384af8] direct3d11 vout display error: Could not Create the D3D11 device. (hr=0x80004001)
[04384af8] direct3d11 vout display error: Direct3D11 could not be opened
[04384af8] direct3d11 vout display error: SetThumbNailClip failed: 0x800706f4
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: There is no one in this community to at least comment something in my post.Such a shame.....

Comment: Here is a clue, maybe: I get the same issue with the actual VLC application, 3.0.16. It happens only when I enable Qt as my interface of choice. Sounds like it isn't a problem with your code, but with the libVLC library's use of Qt.

Comment: any update on this? @Rajkumar

Answer (score 0):

This is also an issue at python-VLC github
https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/issues/155

Comment: So,do you know how to fix it?