# How to find widget new and old winid after WinIdChange Event in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt4

As per PyQt5 doc it is said

> PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.winId()¶
>
> ```
> Return type
>
>     WId
> ```
>
> Returns the window system identifier of the widget.
>
> Portable in principle, but if you use it you are probably about to do something non-portable. Be careful.
>
> If a widget is non-native (alien) and is invoked on it, that widget will be provided a native handle.
>
> This value may change at run-time. An event with type WinIdChange will be sent to the widget following a change in window system
> identifier.

But my question is,does it change any widget's original winId?If yes, how to get the new and old?

Comment: "does it change any widget's original winId?" What do you mean? The doc explains that that value may change, meaning that the "original" (previous) winId will not be valid anymore.

Comment: this happens or not i am not sure!!previously i asked why vlc not playing in frameless and translucent background window.and when i raised an issue at python-vlc.they suggest me to check the winId befor and after several times to check what happens actually

Comment: https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/issues/155. As vlc uses winId() to render i am confused as per doc.because in the doc it is mentioned look above

Comment: `Portable in principle, but if you use it you are probably about to do something non-portable. Be careful.

If a widget is non-native (alien) and is invoked on it, that widget will be provided a native handle.

This value may change at run-time. An event with type WinIdChange will be sent to the widget following a change in window system identifier.`

Comment: My previous vlc problem if you know something which will help me.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725900/vlc-wont-work-with-framelesswindow-and-transparent-translucent-background-in-py

Comment: In my opinion there is something for which i dont get original winId so my video wont render in that frame in case of ` frameless and translucent background window`.

Comment: (Please avoid continuous multiple short comments, it's annoying) I cannot help you with that, but it's clear that there's a problem with frameless and translucent windows, so it's possible that the issue is not about the winId at all. In any case, you could just ensure if the winId remains the same by creating a simple function that prints it at the beginning and then use a QTimer to call it again at regular intervals. Then you could also install an event filter on the target widget and check for `WinIdChange` events.

Comment: It is Continuous, because it is a long issue and I don't write any code here. So trying to explain whole issue .Dont.Mind.

Comment: That event occurred for window not for a single frame.But i can not see any difference of getting winId of that frame at time interval.What does it mean if that event occurred?.@musicamante

Comment: Please, again, do **NOT** write comments continuously. Wait until you have enough to say, then write a *single* comment. If you have to test something, test it and *then* comment. Really, it's very, *very* annoying: this is *not* a chat nor a forum. If the winId remains the same, then the issue is not about that, and if even the python-vlc users and devs can't help you, you'll need to wait until the problem is solved or somebody answers there or on the forum. You have to be *patient*, you cannot expect to always have immediate answers, especially for relatively uncommon situations like yours.

Comment: Bdw thanks for your time.I will keep in mind.